# MySQL Select from UNION performance issue (kills database)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, union

I have a little problem regarding MySQL

I'm trying to make a UNION of two tables like so:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `post_id`, `requested_on`
   FROM `a` 
      WHERE `status` != 'cancelled' 

UNION 

SELECT `user_id`, `post_id`, `time` as requested_on 
   FROM `b` 
      WHERE `type` = 'ADD'
```

This query is executed in `Showing rows 0 - 29 (36684 total, Query took 0.0147 sec)`

but when I do

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT `user_id`, `post_id`, `requested_on`
      FROM `a` 
         WHERE `status` != 'cancelled' 

   UNION 

   SELECT `user_id`, `post_id`, `time` as requested_on 
      FROM `b` 
         WHERE `type` = 'ADD' 
) tbl1
```

MySQL dies.

The reason why I want to do this is to `GROUP BY user_id, post_id`

Any ideas why this happens / any workarounds?

later-edit:

This is the SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7f82d/2

The final query is there, which executes in:

`Record Count: 10; Execution Time: 574ms`

574ms for 10 records in my point of view is gigantic.

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle? And which `requested_on` would you like in your ultimate result?

Comment: Please show the final query that you want to do.  And what indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: By dies, do you mean your query takes a long time to execute / uses lots of IO / CPU? Also, `Showing rows 0 - 29 (36684 total... ` would mean the initial query is returning a small subset, whereas the second derived table would need to be evaluated in its entirety for the `GROUP`

Comment: This is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7f82d/2 The fiddle works, but on my local instance & on server it just dies. By dying it means taking a looong time to execute (I don't know how much but maybe more than 10 minutes)

Comment: The final query is in the fiddle, I just want to GROUP BY `user_id`, `post_id` BOTH Tables. My server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu), Server version: 5.5.33 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi

Comment: Related to @Strawberry's question, I'd like the first `requested_on` with the smallest time in my last result, but that's not necessary, the first appearance (from table a than table b) will do.

Comment: I found out from where the problem actually was. It was from the fact that I was running the queries in PHPMyAdmin, and worked flawlessly when I UNIONed the 2 SELECTs but when I select from a that query it appears that the pagination of PHPMyAdmin dies and tries to output all the results making the SQL request unresponsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what the problem was from.

It was the fact that I was running the queries in PHPMyAdmin and when I did a `SELECT UNION SELECT` everything was good but when I did 
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT UNION SELECT)`
the pagination system from PHPMyAdmin failed, and PHPMyAdmin was trying to output to my browser a over 30k rows table, that's why the SQL Request hang. :(

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the question:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT user_id, post_id, requested_on
      FROM a
         WHERE status != cancelled
   UNION 
   SELECT user_id, post_id, time as requested_on 
      FROM b 
         WHERE type = ADD 
) tbl1 GROUP BY user_id, post_id
```

means. Assume you have:

A, x, t1
A, x, t2

would you like the row with t1 or t2? If that does not matter lets apply an aggregate function such as MIN:

```
SELECT user_id, post_id, MIN(requested_on) FROM (
   SELECT user_id, post_id, requested_on
   FROM a
   WHERE status <> cancelled
   UNION 
   SELECT user_id, post_id, time as requested_on 
   FROM b 
   WHERE type = ADD 
) tbl1 
GROUP BY user_id, post_id
```

MySQL usually doesn't handle derived tables like this very well, is there any other predicate that you can apply to the parts in the union?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found from where the problem is. It was the fact that I was running the queries in PHPMyAdmin and when I did SELECT UNION SELECT everything was good but when I did SELECT * FROM (SELECT UNION SELECT) the pagination system from PHPMyAdmin failed, and PHPMyAdmin was trying to output to my browser a over 30k rows table, that's why the SQL Request Hang.